# Secure Socket Layer (SSL) failure? [OE101C]

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have a process that uses web services via sockets/https. My code is erroring out all of a sudden when using sockets. I'm guessing it's something to do with progress internal certificate manager.

These are the errors that are occurring.

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Secure Socket Layer (SSL) failure. error code -54:  certificate signature failure: for b0f3e76e.0 in n:\progra~1\oe101c\certs (9318)
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Connection failure for host api.constantcontact.com port 443 transport TCP. (9407)
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Invalid socket object used in WRITE method. (9178)
```

I then decided to get the Cert Chain from the site who's service I was using. I ran this command to get this.

```
openssl s_client -connect api.constantcontact.com:443 -showcerts > certs.out
```

After getting the certs I extracted each one into it's own file and tiled them cert1.cer, cert2.cer and cert3.cer. I registered them with the certutil and the error was still occurring.

I then converted all three of them using this command.

```
openssl x509 -in cert1.cer -out cert1.pem -outform PEM
```

Then tried registering them again and still no solution.

I registered them in proenv this way.

```
certutil -import cert1.pem
```

they imported correctly but I am still getting this error. Is there something that I am missing or could this be something entirely different. In the original error the hash b0f3e76e.0 is in fact being generated by the 3rd cert. I attempted to delete the hash in the certs folder and regenerate it. I'm completely clueless at this point. The app has worked for awhile and i remember having this issue in the past but can't remember what fixed it. Seems as though when someone was changing from a virtual drive to a physical drive that progress is installed on this error started popping back up.

Thanks

Comment: That error could correspond to a tcp/ip error or an error validating the cert. Have you checked your network for potential issues?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I miss understood.  YOu can google the b0f3e76e.0 and try to find the rootCA for it.  Then copy the contents of it and using certutil -import on it to see if that works for you.

For example:

URL https://alphassl.com.ua/support/root.pem

copy and paste it to notepad.  Save it as rootCA.pem

use certutil -import rootCa.pem.  This will give you the certificate the ABL program is looking for to hand shake withthe server you are using for ssl socket connection.

Again sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

The server side may have changed the certificate. YOu may want to re-import the certificate from the server using 
openssl s_client -connect api.constantcontact.com:443 -showcerts > certs.out

Then after doing the import, see which hash formatted file you are getting the error.  You can google it and find the certificate and use certutil -import again for that specific hash formatted certificate.

I had experienced this types of issue before where they all of a suddent change the certificate which can have chain certificates.  Also generates from different certificate authority leveling their own company name.

Answer (score 1):

It also could be that the certificate expired.  I just looked at the rootCA on the URL I have mentioned, the validity is expired.

Validity
            Not Before: Sep  1 12:00:00 1998 GMT
            Not After : Jan 28 12:00:00 2014 GMT

You need to find one that has the valid date for expiration.

Answer (score 1):

this solution is in startup.pf in C:\Progress\OpenEdge, edit and add in last line -sslverify 0 ...

example.

-cpinternal ISO8859-1
-cpstream ISO8859-1
-cpcoll Spanish9
-cpcase Basic
-d dmy
-numsep 44
-numdec 46
-sslverify 0